# How to create a ReadStream from memoryStorage with multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I upload a file to my API using multer:

```
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
      fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    }
})
```

The file appears in `const file = req.files["my_file_name"][0]`

Now I want to create a readStream for this like so:

`fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(stream);`

The problem is, `file.path` is undefined when I'm using `memoryStorage()` with `multer`. How can I make this work with `memoryStorage`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using `memoryStorage` you will not get `file.path`, Your file will be in buffer on your request.

`req.file` will have information `{ fieldname, originalname, encoding, mimetype, buffer }`

**Output Stream on Console**

```
const streamifier = require('streamifier');
streamifier.createReadStream(req.file.buffer).pipe(process.stdout);
```

**Read & Write Stream as File**

```
const streamifier = require('streamifier');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/test.png');
streamifier.createReadStream(req.file.buffer).pipe(writeStream);
```

Reference : [File information](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information)